# I m trying to Retrieve the data from XML File into an IPhone application

Tags: objective-c

The XML File Which i used is :

```
<note>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  <URL>http://192.168.1.75/one.png</URL>
</note>
```

In this XML I have retrieve the text but i failed to display the image from the link in the XML File.
I want to display the image in table cell.I have given the coding which i used as follows.

In RootViewController.m

```
@implementation RootViewController

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [appDelegate.books count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];




    cell.text = aBook.heading;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    // Set up the cell
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller

    if(bdvController == nil)
        bdvController = [[BookDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    bdvController.aBook = aBook;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bdvController animated:YES];
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Uncomment the following line to add the Edit button to the navigation bar.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    appDelegate = (XMLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    self.title = @"Books";
}
```

XMLAppDelegate.m:

```
@implementation XMLAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navigationController, books;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {


    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://192.168.1.75/second.xml"];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    //Initialize the delegate.
    XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

    //Set delegate
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

    //Start parsing the XML file.
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

    if(success)
        NSLog(@"No Errors");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");

    // Configure and show the window
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Book.m:

```
@synthesize heading, body, URL;
```

XMLParser.m:

```
@implementation XMLParser

- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser {

    [super init];

    appDelegate = (XMLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"note"]) {

        appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"note"]) {


    }

    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

    if(!currentElementValue) 
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"note"]) {
        [appDelegate.books addObject:aBook];

        [aBook release];
        aBook = nil;
    }
    if([elementName compare:@"heading"]==0) {
        aBook.heading=currentElementValue;

    }
    if([elementName compare:@"body"]==0) {
        aBook.body=currentElementValue; 
    }
    if([elementName compare:@"URL"]==0) {
        aBook.URL=currentElementValue;


    }

    else 
        [aBook setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];

    [currentElementValue release];
    currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

BOOk DetailViewController.m:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        cell.text=aBook.heading;
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        cell.text=aBook.body;
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 2)
    {

        cell.image=aBook.URL;

    }
        return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *sectionName = nil;

    switch(section)
    {
        case 0:
            sectionName = [NSString stringWithString:@"Title"];
            break;
        case 1:
            sectionName = [NSString stringWithString:@"Author"];
            break;
        case 2:
            sectionName = [NSString stringWithString:@"Summary"];
            break;
    }

    return sectionName;
}
```

Comment: I tried to clean it up, but there's some missing code.

Comment: When people come to me and say "here's my code; fix it for me", I respond with my hourly rate.

Comment: what is the question you wish to ask?

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.image=aBook.URL;
```

An URL does not an image make. (Hint: create an UIImage from the contents of the URL.)

Answer (score 0):

you have to get image from URL. you can not display image directly from url.

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL : url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];

this code will help you.

Comment: or you can useUIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]]];